# Angular $anchorScroll ID remains in the url and not working after refresh

Tags: angularjs, anchor-scroll

I have a problem with angular `$anchorScroll`, follwing the [offical doc's](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll), `gotoBottom` example. after clicking on `goToBottm`, `$anchorScroll` is adding to the `url` the `ID` of the location - `mysite.com/tag/##ID`, on the first load it works fine but when `refershing` the page the `ID` stays at the end of the `url`, and the scroll is not working.
Any ideas on how to fix this? my code:
HTML:

```
<button ng-click = "addRow(); gotoBottom()">add row </button>
```

And the ID :

```
<table id = "bottom">
...
</table>
```

gotoBottom in my `controller`:

```
$scope.gotoBottom = function() {
  // set the location.hash to the id of
  // the element you wish to scroll to.
  $location.hash('bottom');

  // call $anchorScroll()
  $anchorScroll();
};
```

Comment: same as the documation, still post it?

Comment: Yes please. Since something is not working for you.

Comment: Posting, if there is more needed I will post as well.

Comment: @Chinni posted, the function is working, just can't get rid of the ## at the end of my url.

Comment: So you don't want that `##ID` ?

Comment: It sticks to the URL, even after refreshing.

Comment: It is the default behaviour right? It sticks to the url and the view will be anchored to your `id`

Comment: Yes the default behaviour works fine, after refreshing the page it goes wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Can you call this method 'gotoBottom' inside of your 'addRow' after your row has added? My guess is that it can't scroll as it might be executed even before the row was added.

So remove gotoBottom from your html

```
<button ng-click = "addRow();">add row </button>
```

And add that to the addRow function

```
$scope.addRow = function(){
 // code for adding a row
 gotoBottom();
}
```

Comment: Trying and posting the result.

Comment: - not working, the '##ID' remains at the end of the url.

Comment: Can you post a plunker or a snippet here?

Comment: It is the same as the documation.